# How to repeat a dataframe - python

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a simple csv dataframe as follow:

```
Date,Data
2000-01-31,9
2000-02-28,8
2000-03-31,7
2000-04-30,6
2000-05-31,5
2000-06-30,4
2000-07-31,3
2000-08-31,2
2000-09-30,1
2000-10-31,0
2000-11-30,11
2000-12-31,12
```

I would like to repeat this dataframe over 10 years, with the year stamp changing accordingly, as follow:

```
Date,Data
2000-01-31,9
2000-02-28,8
2000-03-31,7
2000-04-30,6
2000-05-31,5
2000-06-30,4
2000-07-31,3
2000-08-31,2
2000-09-30,1
2000-10-31,0
2000-11-30,11
2000-12-31,12
2001-01-31,9
2001-02-28,8
2001-03-31,7
2001-04-30,6
2001-05-31,5
2001-06-30,4
2001-07-31,3
2001-08-31,2
2001-09-30,1
2001-10-31,0
2001-11-30,11
2001-12-31,12
....
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df1 = pd.concat([df] * 10)
date_fix =  pd.date_range(start='2000-01-31', freq='M', periods=len(df1))
df1['Date'] = date_fix
df1
```

[out]

```
    Date    Data
0   2000-01-31  9
1   2000-02-29  8
2   2000-03-31  7
3   2000-04-30  6
4   2000-05-31  5
5   2000-06-30  4
6   2000-07-31  3
... ... ...
5   2009-06-30  4
6   2009-07-31  3
7   2009-08-31  2
8   2009-09-30  1
9   2009-10-31  0
10  2009-11-30  11
11  2009-12-31  12
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just using `concat`

```
n=2
Newdf=pd.concat([df]*n,keys=range(n))
Newdf.Date+=pd.to_timedelta(Newdf.index.get_level_values(level=0),'Y')
Newdf.reset_index(level=0,drop=True, inplace=true)
```